I've seen religious subreddits that have "permanent" flair under the usernames. We should do that
We should have something like this as an optional thing.


I'm not opposed to the idea, but there's no reason you can't just put it in your profile. Also, if you get an [tag:orthodox] badge it's even more proof.  It wasn't a very popular idea the first time an idea like this was suggested https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/is-there-an-option-to-specify-your-religious-affiliation/4481#4481

@PeterTurner It would make answers significantly easier to "decode" because people will answer with their denominational flavor, and if you are just some "regular person" who is unaware of the differences then you might accept a perspective that is objectively incorrect for your personal faith. This is why I routinely post that "this is my understanding based on an Orthodox Church perspective..." or "The position of the EO church is that..." etc. Otherwise a general question about doctrine will be a mess of Mormons, JW, Protestants, Calvinists, Catholics, and Orthodox... who all have an answer

that's precisely why I really try hard to stop people from asking general questions about doctrine.  We can't fix stackexchange, they've never implemented a single feature that we've requested and I doubt we make them much money.

@PeterTurner I actually like the general questions about doctrine, as long as people say which "sect" they are from it is okay. It gets really murky when it's just an answer underneath the tag "catholic" when it is clearly not catholic.

yeah, I like 'em too - which is a conflict of interest for a moderator who is tasked with squashing fun and interesting topics.

@PeterTurner This is why I don't envy being a moderator, I get to be selectively squashful of these things. I'll try to be better about it
